# Can a 72V, 50Ah lithium battery be disassembled? I need two 72V, 20Ah batteries

Tags: batteries

I have a [72V, 50Ah lithium battery.](https://batteryswapcabinet.com/product/72v-50ah-lithium-ion-electric-motorcycle-battery-pack/) I want to take out its cells and turn it into two separate batteries.

Answer (score 3):

Theoretically, you could open it and separate the cells. This is however somewhat dangerous (you are on the wrong side of the protection circuitry, so if you create a short circuit, there is a real risk of the battery exploding/catching fire and/or whatever piece of metal (ex : tool) making the short circuit melting (I have seen it happen) with risk of severe burns / metal projections.

So excepted if you are trained to work on the inside of "high power" lithium batteries, I would strongly advise against it.

If you still persist, plan on HEAVY protection equipment (safety glasses are mandatory, I would advise no skin exposed at all (you might end up in a fire blast)). Plan also ahead on what to do in case of a lithium battery fire (NB: water will just make things worse).

Please note that I'm NOT trained to work on lithium batteries (it would have been another week or so in the electrical safety training I took), so I might not know about all the risks involved.

Supposing you do manage to safely separate the cells (or get someone trained do it for you, which I would advise), then you might be lucky and find there is an even number of series strings of cells. In this case, it's easy to separate your battery in 2 smaller set of cells.

If you get an odd number of strings in parallel (about 50% likelihood), then you will get different capacities for your 2 new sets of cells (might be OK for you or not).

If there is a single string of big cells, then you can't do anything (you might manage to get 2 blocks of 36 V 50 Ah).

If the cells are first connected in parallel, and then in series, then it gets more complicated: you have to separate each parallel group in 2, and then re-assemble them into your 2 batteries.

And once you get your 2 pseudo-batteries (all your cells connected in 2 groups), you still have a last big issue: you no longer have a BMS (battery management system), which is absolutely mandatory for lithium batteries this side: it's the BMS that protects against short circuits (risk of explosion), overloading (risk of explosion), under-voltage (risk of explosion at the next charging), unbalancing (=some cells overloaded and others under-loaded -> risk of explosion), ... And you can't reuse the existing one, because it is configured for a battery twice as big (so over-current protection will kick in far too late).

So between the very real safety issues, the risk of the cell configuration not being in your favor and the cost to buy 2 new BMS, I would advise you not to do it. If you do, ask someone with experience in wiring the internals of lithium batteries to do it for you or with you.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can, if the the battery structure is parallel connected series modules.